# How can I do a bulk delete with Spring JPA repository?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I just wrote a `@Scheduled` method which deletes old rows from a table.

```java
@Component
class MyScheduledTasks {

    @Scheduled(...)
    public void purge_MyEntity() {
        LocalDateTime max = ...;
        repository.deleteAllByCreatedDateBefore(max);
    }
}
```

And the log shows that the repository

- first selects all entities by condition
- and then remove each of them one by one

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE

DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...
DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...
DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...
DELETE FROM ... WHERE ...
DELETE FROm ... WHERE ...
```

How can I make the repository execute a single `DELETE FROM` statement?

Comment: have you tried ‘deleteAllInBatch‘?

Comment: Hi Jin, Jayesh has a point. After taking entities which you are going to delete, you can call deleteAllInBatch(Iterable<Entity>) function for bulk purging.

Comment: The problem is that JPA needs to know **what** to delete. Your entity can have relationships with a CASCADE.ALL or DELETE and those need to be deleted as well. Doing a `DELETE FROM ... WHERE ..` won't do that and could even prevent deletion if it the record was linked to something else with a FK constraint it would fail. Hence it first needs to do a select to determine all that. If you are sure this isn't the case, write your own `@Query` for it.